# Cocoa, how to know which operations can be called outside of main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa, sdk, thread-safety

How to know if i can execute a function from system SDK outside of the main thread?

Is there a rule of thumb?

like example this function from CoreBluetooth

```
- (void)connectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral options:(NSDictionary *)options;
```

can be exceed from other thread as main thread or not?

the docs don't state this

Answer (score 1):

Generally, all UI related code has to run on the main thread, everything else can run on a separate thread unless stated in the documentation. So, it looks like that method you specified can run on a background thread.